# Setup maven java project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

How can I make Eclipse manage the classes of a project built by maven? I'm currently using the `Spring Tool Suite` distribution of eclipse, and the project I'm working on uses a maven project root `pom` and a number of `pom` submodules which I wouldn't like to modify.

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html

Comment: Could you post your pom.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the m2e plugin. It allows you to import git projects as maven projects and automatically organizes them in working sets and projects according to maven modules.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of Maven is to let it manage the dependencies and the build process of your application, instead of your IDE. So if you somehow think you need to do it with your IDE instead, you probably do something wrong using Maven.

Comment: I like to have code highlight and autocompletion, which maven alone doesn't provide.

Comment: You don't understand what I said.